# Why is this m.request called twice

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'm using Mithrill v1.0.0, here's the code

```
var scrollable = {};

scrollable.Product = {
    list : [],
    loadList : function(store){
        m.request({
            method : "GET",
            url : "APIUrl" + store,
            withCredentials : true
        }).then(function(result){
            scrollable.Product.list = result;
        })
    }
}

scrollable.oninit = function(){
    scrollable.Product.loadList("authentic")
}

scrollable.view  = function(){
    console.log(scrollable.Product.list.result) //Here's give me two line log
}
```

On the console, its give me two line log, the first one is undefined, and the second one an array with API result values.

Comment: seems loadList is asynchronous - I'll let you fill in the rest

Answer (score 2):

> A call to `m.request` return a promise and trigger a redraw upon completion of its promise chain.
>
> [*m.request docs*](http://mithril.js.org/request.html#how-it-works.)

It's drawing twice, once initially and then once again when your `m.request` completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Mithrill but coming from a ReactJS perspective, I'm guessing that the change in state due to the async call resolution triggers a rerender (i.e. runs`scrollable.view`again).

Here's what I think happens:

1. Initial state: `list` is empty
2. `scrollable.oninit` runs: async method; does not resolve at once.
3. `scrollable.view` runs: console prints still empty `list`.
4. async method in `2` resolves. `list` is assigned fetched values.
5. State change detected, triggering `scrollable.view` to run again. Console now prints `list` with API values.